# What is the safe way to upgrade React Native project?

Tags: react-native

I'm learning React Native. RN has upgrade documentation. But there are only 2 lines of code. After you type it, the project completely crashed. Build failed. All Google results returned old issues and they almost can not help. I tried 2 times but got brick in the head both. Luckily I had pushed everything into Github before I upgraded.

I'm using 0.25, and want to up 0.26. I can stay in 25 for now, but what if in future, when I really need to upgrade for, maybe, security patch, what is a safe way (step) I should follow in order not crash the project?

Thank you.

---

Some images:
[image: 4 errors]
[image]

---

**Update:**

I'm trying to clone the project and update (over and over) and choose something difference in the work through the prompts options, let's see which option is right.

- Followed the 1, 2, 3 suggestion and also browsed to Github issues #4968, still did not help.
- Chose "Overwrite": Failed.
- Chose "Do not overwrite": Still failed.

Comment: Did you run `react-native upgrade` and work through the prompts? Did you also update your app with regards to the posted breaking change? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.26.0. React now has to be required in addition to React Native (separate dependency).

Comment: @BradBumbalough Yes I did. Even I chose overwrite or not, project still built fail after that.

Comment: Did you run `npm install --save react` and update your app to require require Components from React vs React-Native (`let React = require('react')`

Comment: I have faced the problem with new update in 0.26, and I know how to solve. So yes, I do add things you mentioned. Can I ask another question: Which option should I choose when the work through the prompts? I have something manually added into Xcode like Vector Icons, so should I choose "Do not overwrite"?

Comment: Great question. If you hit the `d` key during the upgrade it will show you the diff. I wouldn't overwrite those files... if you need to you can always create a new app with `react-native init` and compare the files manually.

Comment: Yes, I have just checked the diff and found out, that the new conflict files will delete some config (of my Vector Icons package) out of them. So I chose "Do not overwrite". Result still remains: ** BUILD FAILED **

Comment: Thank you for your time Brad, I found out the problem. The default `npm install --save react` only installs v.14, and it needs v.15.0.2 to work with RN 0.26

Comment: Awesome! glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out:

`npm install --save react` is not enough, because I got a warn, it needs 15.0.2

So `npm install --save react@15.0.2` solved my problem (after followed 3 steps in red warning screen.)

If you still get build failed, with `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::terminate()", referenced from:` error, you need to add `-lc++` in `Other Linker Flags` in your xcode project build settings.

Check out this issue for more information https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7566

Answer (score 4):

### [`react-native-git-upgrade`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/12/05/easier-upgrades.html)

Thanks to the ingenuity and hard work of [@ncuillery](https://twitter.com/ncuillery), we now have a much better way to manage React Native upgrades that leverage git's mature merging system.

Read the official React Native blog post here: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/12/05/easier-upgrades.html

And the recently revised upgrading docs here: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/upgrading.html

Thanks Nicolas!

Comment: I'm not working with RN anymore but still thanks, will check it when I have time.